# Having a hard time to understand what Vagrant wants or how it works (Vagrant on Windows, provider vmware_esxi)

Tags: vagrant, esxi

I am trying to follow the directions on this page https://github.com/josenk/vagrant-vmware-esxi and I am using Vagrant on a windows machine (win 10) and I want to be able to deploy VMs on a standalone ESXI6.5 Server (free edition-demo license expired) . No VCenter here.

I am using this command line

vagrant up --provider=vmware_esxi

```
root@110.10.10.10 password:
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'vmware_esxi' provider...
==> default: Box 'cdua/ubuntu16' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: vmware_esxi, vmware, vmware_desktop, vmware_fusion, vmware_workstation
    default: Box Version: 16.04
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'cdua/ubuntu16'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/cdua/ubuntu16
The box you're attempting to add doesn't support the provider
you requested. Please find an alternate box or use an alternate
provider. Double-check your requested provider to verify you didn't
simply misspell it.

If you're adding a box from HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, make sure the box is
released.

Name: cdua/ubuntu16
Address: https://vagrantcloud.com/cdua/ubuntu16
Requested provider: ["vmware_esxi", "vmware", "vmware_desktop", "vmware_fusion", "vmware_workstation"]
```

and here is my Vagrantfile

```
    #
#  Fully documented Vagrantfile available
#  in the wiki:  https://github.com/josenk/vagrant-vmware-esxi/wiki
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|

  config.vm.box = "cdua/ubuntu16"
  config.vm.box_version = "16.04"
  config.vm.synced_folder('.', '/vagrant', type: 'nfs', disabled: true)
  config.vm.network 'private_network', type: "dhcp"
  config.vm.network "public_network", auto_config: false

  config.vm.provider :vmware_esxi do |esxi|
    esxi.esxi_hostname = '10.10.10.10'
    esxi.esxi_username = 'root'
    esxi.esxi_password = 'prompt:'
    esxi.esxi_virtual_network = ['Production','VM Network']
    esxi.guest_name = 'VagrantTestVM'
  end
end
```

I can't understand what vagrant wants from me.
As far as I could google/read I can see that the provider is the plugin used to upload the VM. When it comes to VMWare there are a couple of types of provider and on the hashicorp site none is listed as vmware_esxi. The closest one functionally speaking should be the vmware_ovf which the image cdua/ubuntu16 supports. 
Yet vagrant fails but it tells me that the box provider is vmware_esxi

Update:
Before posting here I tried the below, as you can see error again

```
  vagrant up --provider=vmware_esxi

root@10.10.10.10 password:
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'vmware_esxi' provider...
==> default: Box 'generic/ubuntu1710' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
default: Box Provider: vmware_esxi, vmware, vmware_desktop, vmware_fusion, vmware_workstation
default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'generic/ubuntu1710'
default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/generic/ubuntu1710
==> default: Adding box 'generic/ubuntu1710' (v1.8.50) for provider: vmware
default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/generic/boxes/ubuntu1710/versions/1.8.50/providers/vmware.box
default: Download redirected to host: vagrantcloud-files-production.s3.amazonaws.com
default: Progress: 100% (Rate: 3286k/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
The box you attempted to add doesn't match the provider you specified.

Provider expected: vmware
Provider of box: vmware_desktop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the provider you linked [supports every `vmware` box format except `vmware_ovf`](https://github.com/josenk/vagrant-vmware-esxi/blob/master/lib/vagrant-vmware-esxi/plugin.rb#L15), which is [the only format provided for the `cuda/ubuntu16` box](https://app.vagrantup.com/cdua/boxes/ubuntu16).  You probably need too change `config.vm.box` to a different box that supports one of the other formats.

You might check [Hashicorp's box index for "vmware" format Ubuntu boxes](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=downloads&provider=vmware&q=ubuntu).  (I've had good luck in the past with [`bento/ubuntu-16.04`](https://app.vagrantup.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-16.04) and it claims a `vmware_desktop` build.)

Comment: see the update. your suggestion failed as well. There don's seem to be an image that would work

Comment: This one worked. bento/ubuntu-18.04 Quite frustratring process, Thanks for the feedback.